# Tkinter Binding a function to left mouse button not working

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.4

for some reason binding a function that finds the x and y coordinates to a mouse click event just isn't working, when I left click absolutely nothing happens, but if I call out the function in the actual code it runs fine. I tried other solutions posted on this site but they did not seem to help.
using python 3.4
Here's my exact code:

```
#Import TKINTER toolset:
from tkinter import *

#Starting variables:
#Defining mouse x and y coordinates
global mouse_x
global mouse_y
mouse_x = 0
mouse_y = 0

#Main window:
window = Tk()

#Workspace and Canvas:
wrkspace =  Frame(window, bg="red",width=640,height=480)
canvas = Canvas(wrkspace,bg="white",width=640,height=480)

#Keyframe editor: (DO LATER)

#Displays mouse x and y on workspace:
def find_mouse_xy():
    mouse_x = wrkspace.winfo_pointerx()
    mouse_y = wrkspace.winfo_pointery()
    print ("x: " + str(mouse_x))
    print ("y: " + str(mouse_y))

wrkspace.bind("<Button-1>",find_mouse_xy)

wrkspace.pack()
canvas.pack()

#Runs window:
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: you are binding to a frame. Are you intending for the binding to work when you click on the canvas?

Comment: yes, should the canvas not be there?

Comment: It's your canvas, it can be there or not. The point is, only the widget that has the binding will see the event.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Canvas` is catching the mouse event, but you have it bound to your `Frame`.

Try binding it to the canvas instead.

```
canvas.bind("<Button-1>",find_mouse_xy)
```

Also, you will need an argument for your `find_mouse_xy()` function for the event that will be passed to it.

```
def find_mouse_xy(event):
```

Comment: Fantastic, the function is being called when I click now :) However, the actual x and y coordinates displayed are incorrect. This i veering off topic slightly but when i click in the very top left corner of the canvas it tells me that the x coordinate is 83 and y is 37 when they should both be 1.

Comment: Then maybe you should replace wrkspace.winfo_pointerx() with canvas.winfo_pointerx(). And the same for y.